# Redirect output of remote application to telnet

Tags: c#, output, windows-ce, telnet

I am starting a C# windows form application remotely using telnet. The remote application is on a WindowsCE device. I want the output of the remote application to show in the telnet terminal on my PC after I start it.

I accomplished this by setting the "output type" to "Console Application" in the project properties of the remote application.

***My question is:*** when I close the telnet terminal on my PC, where does the output of the remote application go? Will it fill up some buffer and crash the application?

The remote application uses log4net and has both a ConsoleAppender and a FileAppender.

Let me know if you need any more details.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing why don't you try.

I would advise a special `Console Reader` looking for a `Goodbye message` which would be sent on exit.